# White space pattern in Lucene/Java

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I'm trying to do a code analyzer in Java with Lucene. I want to remove whitespaces to normalize the code. My problem is that it doesn't recognize "\s*" or "\s+" regular expression. So this is my code:

```
Analyzer ana = CustomAnalyzer.builder(Paths.get("."))
    .addCharFilter("patternreplace","pattern","[{]|[}]|[;]|[,]|[(]|[)]","replacement","")
    .withTokenizer(SimplePatternSplitTokenizerFactory.class,"pattern","[\n]") 
    .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
    .addTokenFilter("patternreplace","pattern","[jlk][+][+]","replacement","i++")
    .addTokenFilter("patternreplace","pattern","size","replacement","length")
    .addTokenFilter("patternreplace","pattern","[\\s*][jkl][\\s*]","replacement"," i ")
    .addTokenFilter("patternreplace","pattern","[\\s+]","replacement","")
    .build();
    return muestraTexto(ana, texto);
```

This is the code example I am using:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < nada.size(); i++){
    suma = 5 + 3;
}


    for(int j = 0; j < algo.size(); j++){
    suma2 = 5+3;
}
```

And this is my output:

```
forint i = 0 i < nada.length i
suma = 5  3

forint j = 0 j < algo.length i
    suma2 = 53
```

So it's not removing the whitespaces.

Comment: Notes: (1) You are using `[` and `]` in various places. Content inside square brackets like these in a regex is interpreted as a list of characters to find. So `[s*]` means "every `s` and every `*`". Is that what you want? You can test your regexes using [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) but bear in mind Lucene's regex functionality is [limited](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html?is-external=true).

Comment: (2) `PatternReplaceCharFilter` is a char filter - not a token filter, so maybe `.addTokenFilter("patternreplace" ...` does not work the way you expect. I have not tested that.